# If custom taxonomy exist on post?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, array

I have custom taxonomy called ‘filter’ and if the post has the ‘filter’ ‘reel’ I want to use this loop else use another.

```
$work_tax = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'filter' );

if (array_key_exists('reel', $work_tax)) {
    get_template_part( 'loop', 'work_feed_reel' );
} else {
    get_template_part( 'loop', 'work_feed' );
}
```

How should I write that if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) to check if a post is in a specific term.

```
if ( has_term( 'reel', 'filter', $post->ID ) ) {
    get_template_part( 'loop', 'work_feed_reel' );
} else {
    get_template_part( 'loop', 'work_feed' );
}
```